# Updating Dictionary items requires multiple publishes

Tags: publishing, dictionary

Whenever I edit a dictionary phrase in the Content Editor, after I hit save, the change is reflected in the Experience Editor, which is great. However, I want to see this change in my web database as well, so I hit `publish -> publish item` and it publishes the item from master to web.

The issue is that it sometimes takes up to 8 publishes before the change is finally in my prod db.

It seems to be related with the dictionary cache not being updated properly.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What is your sitecore version?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Sitecore 9. I was reading that this issue should be fixed in Sitecore 9, but I guess for some reason I'm still getting it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the comments above, you'll require to create an event handler which will reset the cache of the dictionary. The event handler will be executed on the events `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote`.

If I am not mistaken, the items are available on the target database (web) after publish but it reads the dictionary from a file (`.dat`). So, it is the file that is still not yet updated.

I haven't yet jump into a deep dive on how the dictionary cache clear works but out of my mind, I think it is periodically updating the file, say every minute or 2.

**Code Snippet**

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Globalization;

public class ResetDictionaryCache
{
    public void DictionaryClearCache(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Translate.ResetCache();
        Log.Info("Dictionary Cache has been reset", this);
    }
}
```

Once that you have implemented the `ResetDictionaryCache` event handler, you will need to create a config patch for the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote`.

**Config Patch**

```
<event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Your.Namespace.ResetDictionaryCache, YourAssemblyName" method="DictionaryClearCache" />
</event>

<event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Your.Namespace.ResetDictionaryCache, YourAssemblyName" method="DictionaryClearCache" />
</event>
```

You can also use the overload method `ResetCache(bool removeFileCache)`. Just pass it `true` and it will delete the file and then it will get rebuilt.

You'll still need the above if you are experiencing the below issues:

- Dictionary items showing Key value instead of Phrase text
- Dictionary cache not getting updated in remote instances such as CD servers
- Dictionary entry shows incorrect value by Translate.Text(“Keyword”) with Fallback language item turned on

Reference: [Troubleshooting Issues with Sitecore Dictionary in Multi Lingual Solutions](https://horizontalintegration.blog/2017/11/25/troubleshooting-issues-with-sitecore-dictionary-in-multi-lingual-solutions/)

Comment: Would this have an impact on the performance of the CD server?

Comment: Not as far as i know because once the cache is re populated, it will read the value from the cache

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you so much!